Is there a way to apply a custom route_class for every APIRouter in your fastapi application?
Is there a way to apply a custom route_class for every single APIRouter in your fastapi app?  Similar to this, but instead of creating each APIRouter instance passing the parameter, I'd like to apply that for all with a single declaration.  I can't seem to find how to do that in the docs.
One thing I find odd is that I can set the route_class in the same file where the router is defined, but if I try to do it in the main function (where include_router() is called), it seems to have no effect.  Why is this?
Thanks in advance for any guidance.

did you find the way how to do it ? Right now im using my custom route class for each of my controllers.py files for different resources

@tripod  hello did you find any solution i am also facing this issue.

@MahmudulHassan Didn't care too much about it and settled with common custom route class for each of my controller files dedicated to different domain/resource

The default APIRoute class is the default value in APIRouter's __init__.  If you want to change this one option I can think of is to subclass the APIRouter and provide the same set of parameters for its __init__ and then fill the default value of route_class parameter with your desired class. Then in your application you can instantiate this subclass instead of APIRouter.
Another very simple option is to have a function responsible for creating a router. Inside that function you instantiate the APIRouter with the desired route_class parameter:
def create_router() -> APIRouter:
    return APIRouter(route_class=TimedRoute)

router = create_router()

@router.get("/timed")
async def timed():
    return {"message": "It's the time of my life"}

